# IntellliJ 2018 + Exploded War + Tomcat: Issue with filtered index.html

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I'm having following issue:

I'm working with a new project which is a web application packed into a war and deployed on a tomcat with the exploded war artefact. I'm doing this with Intellij like a hundred times before, so I'm quite experienced with that.

But with this new project the problem is a specific maven build which adds two parameters (-Dclient and another one). Those parameters are put into some paths in the index.html for assets. If I do some changes to the index.html, the new index.html is being loaded, BUT the parameter values inside the html are lost, it renders e.g. "${client}" instead of the actual name, because I think the html is hotdeployed and not refiltered by maven anymore. Can I change this behaviour? What can I do? Hope I could make the issue understandable...

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78963 - it is not yet possible to configure resources filtering in IDE during hot application reload.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the info! Doesn't look like it has a high priority for Jetbrains though... :-(